# How to change column/row data into row only data (for db import)?

Tags: excel, powerquery, spreadsheet, unpivot

I don't know much about Excel but I think it may be capable of doing this. I have a large spreadsheet similar to the first image that I need to "spread out" into separate rows for each header column with its corresponding values in one row. So the first spreadsheet basically needs to look like the second spreadsheet (with all the rows, since I only listed the first few). Is there a quick way of this doing in Excel? And apologies in advance for the title to this post. I really didn't know how else to phrase this question. But if someone can come up with a better way to phrase it, I will be happy to change it (if I can do that).

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: Hello Gooseman, before I get into the ways of doing this. Can I ask why you need the table sorted in this fashion? There may be alternative depending on what you do with the data afterwards eg. (to put on a chart, query data from etc.)

Comment: You are looking to 'unpivot' the table. Something like this may help you -  [Superuser Unpivot](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Comment: @Calico I need to import this data into a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Excel 2013/2016 than this is a simple task which can be solved using Unpivot data function inside Power Query Window.

first, select your table (make sure you give name to your first column), then go to `Data` ==> `From Table`

[image]

You will automatically launch PowerQuery window. from there, select all your columns (you can click on first column (110 column), then scroll to last column and select it while holding `SHIFT` button). When all columns are selected, goto `Transform tab` ==> `Unpivot Columns`.

[image]

After that, goto `Home` tab ==>`Close&Load`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately I don't see Data->From Table option. I'm using Excel 2010.